# Access vertex data stored in VBO in the shader

Tags: opengl, java, shaders, glsl

If I wanted to store extra data in a VBO for skinning (indices for indexing into an array of matrices of bones and floats for applying weights to those bones) How would I go about accessing that data in GLSL? I already know how to put the data in the buffer, interleaved with the rest of the data.

For example I want each vertex for a model to contain:

```
Vec3 position;
Vec3 normal;
Vec4 color;
Vec2 texCoords;
int boneCount;
int[3] boneIndex;
float[3] boneWeight;
```

Then drawing like:

```
bind(vertexBufferID);
glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, stridePlus, 0 * 4);
glNormalPointer(GL11.GL_FLOAT, stridePlus, 3 * 4);
glColorPointer(4, GL11.GL_FLOAT, stridePlus, (3 + 3) * 4);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, stridePlus, (3 + 3 + 4) * 4);
glVertexPointer(7, GL11.GL_FLOAT, stridePlus, (3 + 3 + 4 + 2) * 4);
glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, VPNCTEnd);
```

Then in my vertex shader I want:

```
 //Get indices of bones
 //Get weights of bones
 //Get bone transforms
 //for each bone transform, apply it to gl_Position at the specified weight
```

What is the GLSL required for the last part of the process? It seems like I need to set a attribute pointer to the data somehow, but I'm not sure where to do that when the data is stored in the VBO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you probably want to use [`glVertexAttribPointer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribPointer) on the application side to specify all the components, including the bone stuff, rather than the deprecated glVertexPointer and friends.  Something like:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, 0 * 4);  // Position
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, 3 * 4);  // Normals
// etc.
glVertexAttribPointer(4, 3, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, stride, (3 + 3 + 4 + 2) * 4);  // Bone indices
glVertexAttribPointer(5, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (3 + 3 + 4 + 2 + 3) * 4);  // Bone weights
```

You don't need a separate attribute for the bone count, since you can just zero the weights of unused slots (and set the index to 0 or something).  The first argument to `glVertexAttribPointer` is the attribute index, and each attribute can store up to 4 values.

You'll also need to use [`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glEnableVertexAttribArray) to tell OpenGL which attributes you're using.

In the GLSL shader, you then access these by declaring them as `attribute` variables, like:

```
attribute vec3 Position;
attribute vec3 Normal;
// etc.
attribute vec3 BoneIndices;
attribute vec3 BoneWeights;
```

Finally, you can control which variables are mapped to which attribute by using [`glBindAttribLocation`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindAttribLocation).  You'd insert a bunch of these calls before linking the shader, which will tell OpenGL the desired correspondence between the variables and the attribute indices used in the `glVertexAttribPointer` calls.  (There are also other ways to set up this mapping; a more in-depth discussion is at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873631/vertex-shader-attribute-mapping-in-glsl).)

Comment: Yeah, whenever I post any of my OpenGL code I hear how outdated it is :) When it comes to the graphics I usually just go with the first thing that works. I'll try out the more up-to-date calls :) I guess I might as well allow 4 bones for each vertex since I can stuff 4 values in the attribute anyway.

Comment: I see your shader code is Cg code? Do you know how to access the attributes in GLSL code instead of Cg?

Comment: @Byte56 Oops. You're right. Fixed!